# Finish one date before moving on to another

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm doing a search where I need to submit a form for one date, scrape a bunch of results, then move onto the next date.

In my parse method, I'm going to loop through the dates, and submit the form for each search.  Each search fires off a couple hundred requests.

Is there a way to wait for those requests to finish before I search the next date?  I need to be able to keep track of what dates have completed when the crawler exits.

```
class DateSpider(scrapy.Spider):

def parse(self, response):
    start_date = datetime.date(2012, 1, 1)
    end_date = datetime.date(2012, 12, 31)
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    d = start_date
    while d <= end_date:
      form_date = d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
      yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
          response,
          formdata={'avEntryDate': form_date},
          callback=self.parseDateSearchResult,
      )
      d += delta

def parseDateSearchResult(self, response):
    # table that creates an additional 500 requests
    # I want these requests to complete before I queue the next dates 500 requests
```

I want to prevent hundreds of thousands of requests getting queued, especially since I need to crawl somewhat slowly and there's no way this whole crawl will finish in one run.  Is there a better way to crawl this one day at a time?

Idea - Can you run a spider, wait for it to finish, then start the spider again with different parameters?

Comment: Can you provide some code please? What you're describing is not entirely clear, especially this bit: "...and submit the form for each search"

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I was clear enough.  Let me simplify things a bit.  One minute.

Comment: Not sure about your question, but why didn't you do `start_date = datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)` and `end_date = datetime.date(2016, 12, 31)` if you're setting those before. Might save you a little time in `parse` if you're calling it repeatedly

Comment: New to python.  I've simplified accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: is this happening inside a simple python script or within a web server? Have you read these? https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#event-driven-networking and https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html#topics-autothrottle

Comment: if it's a python script your run from the command line, you don't have any time limits really, it can run for as long as it needs to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

about waiting for the spider to "finish" and then start again, yes, you can do it with the [`spider_idle` signal](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-idle) which waits for when the spider doesn't have more work to do, I think this spider (with your modifications of course) should work for you:

```
class WaitDateSpider(Spider):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.current_date = datetime(2012, 1, 1)
        self.end_date = datetime(2012, 12, 31)
        super(WaitDateSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.crawler.signals.connect(self.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)

    start_urls = ['http://initialurl.com']

    initial_response = None

    def create_date_request(self, response, date):
        return FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'avEntryDate': date},
            callback=self.parse_date_search_results,
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        self.initial_response = response
        yield self.create_date_request(response, self.current_date)

    def parse_date_search_results(self, response):
        pass

    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        if self.current_date < self.end_date:
            self.current_date += timedelta(days=1)
            self.crawler.engine.crawl(self.create_date_request(self.initial_response, self.current_date), spider)
```

Check that the signal method doesn't actually `yield` a request, but uses `crawler.engine` to add the requests to its queue.

Also I added the `initial_response` attribute because you are using the `from_response` method to create a `FormRequest`.

Comment: Will I still invoke this with the usual `scrapy crawl WaitDateSpider`?

Comment: totally, the signal is now part of your spider because of  `signals.connect`.

Comment: Thanks, this was great and I'm up and running now.  But one note - to make this work for me, I had to move the `signals.connect` stuff into a `def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs)` method.  You can find an example in the top of the document linked by @eLRuLL